# How can I enable a repository or target temporarily and easily disable it without using vim/sed/etc?

Tags: apt, software-sources

I want to be able to temporarily enable `non-free` or `contrib` but I don't want to keep them enabled all the time as I try to utilize open source software as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have or can install `software-properties-common` it gives you an awesome and simple command line tool to do exactly this. You may already have it if you have used a PPA (personal package archive) to install extra software on your system, otherwise you can run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y # the -y accepts a prompt for you
```

I ran into this while trying to install mbrola and the voices for it. The website suggested for grabbing these non-free components seems to be down, so I was looking for alternatives and finally figured out that they were packaged for Debian/Ubuntu, just not available in the default sources.

First, you can check your existing sources to see whether you have non-free or contrib enabled already. This command recursively '-r' searches for anything '' in all files matching sources.list* which includes sources.list.d/ and all files in it and prints out each line of each file preceded by the filename.

```
grep -r '' /etc/apt/sources.list*
# we'll also save this list to a file to easily see which files get updated
grep -r '' /etc/apt/sources.list* > /tmp/apt-lists-before.txt
```

Now to enable `contrib` or `non-free`, they are on separate lines because this tool requires you to only specify one at a time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository non-free
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
```

Then check your sources.list* files again.

```
grep -r '' /etc/apt/sources.list*
# we'll also save this list to a file to easily see which files get updated
grep -r '' /etc/apt/sources.list* > /tmp/apt-lists-after.txt
# compare the two lists
diff /tmp/apt-lists-*
```

If you are satisfied that it added the intended new targets, you can run `sudo apt update` and `apt search mbrola` to see an example of new packages available that weren't before.

```
sudo apt update
apt search mbrola
```

Now you can install the software you want, then disable the `non-free` or `contrib` sources afterwards, which will allow the software to work, but not automatically update. If a new version of some normal package causes issues with the non-free package, you can repeat this process to enable the `non-free` repository again and see if after `sudo apt update` there is an update for the package with `sudo apt --upgradable`.

```
sudo apt install mbrola mbrola-us1 -y # the -y accepts a prompt for you
sudo add-apt-repository --remove contrib
sudo add-apt-repository --remove non-free
```

See also this excellent Q&A that describes only allowing certain non-free packages to update while blocking the rest.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534340/103652